# Use an array of objects to construct a new object that will call functions declared in the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using a JS router for my new website project. The router accepts an object: the Key is the URL address and the Value is a function that will get called when the address is reached.

It gets messy pretty quickly with the amount pages and sub pages growing bigger and bigger, especially considering that different pages need to call different initialization functions (`initAccordion` or `initDataTables`, etc, etc).

Just to keep it neat I thought of creating an array of objects that will hold the page names and the init functions that need to be called after the page is loaded. However the solution I use uses `eval`:

```
function initFoo() {
    console.log("initFoo says hi");
}

function initBar() {
    console.log("initBar says hi");
}

var pages = [
    {
        name: "home",
        init: ["initFoo", "initBar"]
    },
    {
        name: "people",
        init: ["initBar"]
    }
];

var routerPaths = {};

for (var page in pages) {
    var url = pages[page].name;
    var init = pages[page].init;
    // construct the string for eval()
    var objStr = "routerPaths['" + url + "'] = function() {";
    for(var item in init) {
        objStr += init[item] + "();";
    }
    objStr += "};";

    eval(objStr);
}

routerPaths.home();  // as expected: initFoo says hi initBar says hi
routerPaths.people();  // as expected: initBar says hi
```

This all fine, but is there a way to perhaps have the `pages.init` array  without the quotes and the object creator NOT using `eval`? So that the values would look like this `init: [initFoo, initBar]`.

So my questions really are: Is there a way of creating the new `routerPaths` object without constructing a string and then running `eval` on it? Should I just stick with what I have?

Keep in mind that `routerPaths.home`, `routerPaths.people` need to be functions that call the functions from `pages.init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to reference functions by their string names. Just use a function name like any other variable.
    var pages = [
        {
            name: "home",
            init: [initFoo, initBar]
        },
        {
            name: "people",
            init: [initBar]
        }
    ];

and write your `init` stubs as ordinary closures (note: it's imperative to use `let` and not `var` in the loop).

```
var routerPaths = {};

for (var page of pages) {
    let init = page.init;

    routerPaths[page.name] = function() {
        init.forEach(function(fn) { fn() })
    }
}
```

If you can't use ES6 `for...of` and `let`, replace them with `forEach:

```
pages.forEach(function(page) {
    var init = page.init;
    routerPaths[page.name] = function() {
        init.forEach(function(fn) { fn() })
    }
})
```

Comment: This is a front-end router that I am using. Is your solution going to work in a browser?

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski: added an example for older browsers

Comment: Ok ill give it a go

Answer (score 0):

```
const initFoo=()=>{
    console.log("initFoo says hi");
}

const initBar=()=> {
    console.log("initBar says hi");
}

let pages = [
    {
        name: "home",
        init: [initFoo, initBar]
    },
    {
        name: "people",
        init: [initBar]
    }
];

let routerPaths = {
};

for (let page in pages) {
    let url = pages[page].name;
    let init = pages[page].init;
    Object.defineProperty( routerPaths ,  url , {
        value: ()=>{
            for(var item in init) {
                init[item]();
            }
        },  
        enumerable: true, // if enumerable is true then only you can see the people,home properties if you console.log
                          //if enumerable set to false you can not see the the property but you can still call routerPaths.people and it just works fine
    });
}
console.log(routerPaths);

routerPaths.home();  // as expected: initFoo says hi initBar says hi
routerPaths.people();  // as expected: initBar says hi
```